# Connect from New Country without restarting TOR Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

Is it possible to change the IP address without restarting the Tor Browser?

So, each time we start the Tor Browser, it connects through a new node. Would it be possible to do the following?

1. In a Browser such as FireFox, set the SOCKS5 proxy to 127.0.0.1 and port 9050.
2. Keep the Browser Session running.
3. Edit the torrc file with new value for ExitNodes and each time restart the tor service.

For example:

```
ExitNodes {US}
service tor restart
```

After this, edit the node to some other country:

```
ExitNodes {fr}
```

And then restart Tor service again:

```
service tor restart
```

Comment: You can use the control port to make temporary changes to the Tor software or you could also use `kill` to send Tor  a message.